# 色 - A meaning other than color/various?

Tags: meaning

I'm working on translating a news article from Japanese to English. This is one of the sentences:

> 米国は、クアッドで扱うのは新型コロナウイルス対応やクリーンエネルギーなど「実務的な案件」だと強調し、安保色を打ち消そうとしている。

I can't figure out what this use of 色 means. I've looked it up everywhere I can find and am starting to wonder if it is actually an abbreviation of a treaty.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: [色（しょく）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/色_%28しょく%29/)

Answer (score 2):

It's read しょく, and is a suffix that means "mood", "smell", "sign" or "appearance". It follows only a small set of words, including:

- 国際色
- 地方色
- 郷土色
- 対決色
- 保守色

It's also in lexicalized compounds like 敗色, 古色 and 異色.

安保 is short for 安全保障, and it's typically used in the context of [日米安保](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S.%E2%80%93Japan_Alliance). Having 安保色 means stimulating some other countries, as well as some people in Japan.